# How to convert from cartesian to vector form (of a straight line)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

line in question:

$$-x - 1 = \frac 12y - \frac12 = \frac 12z + 1$$

I wasn't really sure how to go about this one since it's not in the exact general form that I was taught, but I went along and tried to do it anyway:

$$-x-1=t \rightarrow x = -t-1$$

$$\frac 12y - \frac 12 =t \rightarrow y = \frac t2+1$$

$$\frac 12z + 1 = t\rightarrow z = \frac t2 - \frac 12$$

and got:

$$(-1, 1, -\frac 12)+t(-1, \frac 12, \frac 12)$$

Is this correct? If not, how do I do this problem?

Comment: That "vector in question" should probably be changed to "straight line in space in question" . Besides this, it looks fine to me.

Comment: Maybe a typo it should be that $y=2t+1$ and $z=2t-2$ With that your solution is $(-1, 1, -2)+t(-1, 2, 2)$